# SQL Query Joining 5 tabelas

Tags: mysql, sql, web-service, query

Preciso de ajuda para fazer uma query (relacionamentos múltiplos) no meu WebService + MySQL para retornar o resultado no meu aplicativo Android.

Tenho essas respectivas tabelas:

[image: Relacionamentos Multiplos]

## Query

Preciso fazer a consulta de uma pessoa(tb_suspeito), com os atributos (Nome, cpf e Rg).

```
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("SELECT...);
```

O retorno que preciso no meu aplicativo Android é uma tabela nesse formato:

[image: Tabela Resultado]

## Pergunta

O query SQL com o SELECT e JOINs deve ser feito tudo em uma única query do Statement?
Como proceder? Criar views seria uma solução para apresentar no Android posteriormente?

Comment: Use SELECT se quiser deixar a consulta na camada do aplicativo (backend) e use VIEW se quiser deixar a consulta na camada de banco de dados. Se quiser ajuda com a query ou view, poste por favor o código que você já tentou até agora.

Comment: A minha dúvida é essa requisição dentro de um envelope SOAP, num resultado de um suspeito com mais de um processo?

Comment: Eu estava buscando a melhor forma de formar o envelope SOAP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta utilizar JOINs simples entre as tabelas, das próximas vezes, faça como o @Caffe disse e adicione suas tentativas e mostre algum esforço, pesquise no site, temos excelentes perguntas sobre joins como por exemplo, a resposta do @Bacco [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/6441/qual-%C3%A9-a-diferen%C3%A7a-entre-inner-join-e-outer-join) é praticamente um artigo completo sobre o tema.

### Com subconsultas

```
SELECT
  A.descricao_artigo,
  P.dt_processo
  SP.descricao_situacao_processo
  P.pdf_Processo
FROM
  processo_judicial P
  INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo SP on P.cd_situacao_processo = SP.cd_situacao_processo
  INNER JOIN tp_artigo A ON O.cd_artigo = A.cd_artigo
WHERE
  P.cd_processo IN (
    SELECT cdProcesso FROM suspeito_Processo WHERE cd_suspeito IN (
      SELECT cd_suspeito FROM suspeito WHERE (/*SUAS condicao de suspeito*/)
    )
  )
```

### JOIN em todas as Tabelas

```
SELECT
  A.descricao_artigo,
  P.dt_processo
  SP.descricao_situacao_processo
  P.pdf_Processo
FROM
  processo_judicial P
  INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo SP on P.cd_situacao_processo = SP.cd_situacao_processo
  INNER JOIN tp_artigo A ON O.cd_artigo = A.cd_artigo
  INNER JOIN suspeito_Processo SUP ON (SUP.cd_processo = P.cd_processo)
  INNER JOIN suspeito S ON (S.cd_suspeito = SUP.cd_suspeito)
WHERE
  WHERE /* SUAS CONDICOES DE SUSPEIRO USANDO O ALIAS S */
```

### Usando EXISTS

```
SELECT
  A.descricao_artigo,
  P.dt_processo
  SP.descricao_situacao_processo
  P.pdf_Processo
FROM
  processo_judicial P
  INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo SP on P.cd_situacao_processo = SP.cd_situacao_processo
  INNER JOIN tp_artigo A ON O.cd_artigo = A.cd_artigo
WHERE
  EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 
    FROM
      suspeito_processo SUP
      INNER JOIN suspeito S ON S.cd_suspeito = SUP.cd_suspeito
    WHERE
      SUP.cd_processo = P.cd_processo AND
      /* SUAS CONDICOES DO SUSPEITO COM ALIAS S
    )
```

Todas essas opções são soluções válidas

Comment: Não sei se usar subquery seria uma boa, talvez fazer todos os joins ficasse melhor.

Comment: Eu fantasio o seguinte cenário: AP faz uma pergunta que é um requisito de software completo; AP se retira para tomar café; AP volta e encontra o requisito de software atendido por alguém não remureado; comunidade de desenvolvedores não ganha nada pois a pergunta como estava não será referência para mais ninguém, portanto as respostas também não. Por isso em vez de responder eu deixei um comentário.

Comment: @Caffé Eu entendo seu ponto de vista, como como disse em um outro comentário numa pergunta de MatLab que está na fila. Quando é a primeira pergunta eu relevo, reforço a questão e espero que entenda. A partir da segunda, presume-se que o AP comece a entender o modelo. Acho q faz parte da política de "Boas Vindas" a comunidade. Como um "Grace Period"

Comment: Primeiramente obrigado pelas as considerações. Só quero salientar que não vim aqui só com o fim de conseguir algo pronto feito por outra pessoa. O que perguntei é o que seria melhor para depois eu poder inserir esse resultado na minha App. Visando uma carga menor sobre a aplicação. Por isso perguntei como proceder? Se criar view seria uma boa?

Sobre os Statements é que eu vi alguns exemplos sendo criados vários statements e posteriormente uma junção destes.

Comment: Já trabalhei com postgreSQL e criação de views para visualização de dados utilizando o Geoserver, porém tenho pouco conhecimento sobre WebService + Soap + Android. Por isso a dúvida, por questão de desempenho e qual é mais fácil para eu recuperar os dados e apresentar na app.

Answer (score 3):

## Uma ou várias consultas

Se tens um objetivo especifico de realizar uma consulta para obter determinada informação organizada de determinada maneira, sim, a forma mais eficaz é uma única consulta à base de dados que te devolva tudo já pronto a usar:

#### Consulta

Assumindo que pretendes consultar referente ao `suspeito` X:

```sql
SELECT
  tp_artigo.descricao_artigo AS descricao_artigo,
  processo_judicial.dt_processo AS dt_processo,
  tp_situacao_processo.descricao_situacao_processo AS descricao_situacao,
  processo_judicial.pdf_processo AS pdf_processo
FROM suspeito
INNER JOIN suspeito_processo ON (
  suspeito_processo.cd_suspeito = suspeito.cd_suspeito
)
INNER JOIN processo_judicial ON (
  processo_judicial.num_processo = suspeito_processo.num_processo
)
INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo ON (
  tp_situacao_processo.cd_situacao_processo = processo_judicial.cd_situacao_processo
)
INNER JOIN tp_artigo ON (
  tp_artigo.cd_artigo = processo_judicial.cd_artigo
)
WHERE suspeito.cd_suspeito = 1
```

#### Resultado da consulta

A consulta em cima realiza uma tarefa especifica que é a recolha dos seguintes dados referentes ao `suspeito` X:

```
┌──────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────────────┬──────────────┐
│ descricao_artigo │ dt_processo │ descricao_situacao │ pdf_processo │
└──────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────────────┴──────────────┘
```

---

## Web service ou MySQL View

Se a consulta é para obter informação geral, ou seja, referente a todos os `suspeito`, uma `VIEW` é o preferível porque torna-se mais prático para atualizar no futuro e também porque não existem dados variáveis a considerar.

Se a consulta é como foi o meu entendido, consultar determinada informação do `suspeito` X, então o *web service* será o caminho a tomar por causa da lógica e validações a fazer aos dados.

**Nota:** Podes ter uma `VIEW` também a receber parâmetros, mas para isso precisas de criar uma função de MySQL. Demasiado trabalho e código a manter, onde aqui também é preferível manter a consulta no *web service*.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.descricao_artigo, p.dt_processo, sp.descricao_situacao_processo, p.pdf_Processo
FROM processo_judicial AS p
INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo as sp on p.cd_situacao_processo = sp.cd_situacao_processo
INNER JOIN tp_artigo as a ON p.cd_artigo = a.cd_artigo
INNER JOIN suspeito_processo AS susp_proc ON p.num_processo = susp_proc.num_processo
INNER JOIN suspeito AS s ON susp_proc.cd_suspeito = s.cd_suspeito
WHERE s.nome = //NOME// AND s.cpf_suspeito = //CPF// AND s. rg_suspeito = //RG//;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public ArrayList<ProcessoJudicial> consultar(String nome_suspeito, String cpf_suspeito, String rg_suspeito){

    ArrayList<ProcessoJudicial> results = new ArrayList<ProcessoJudicial>();

    try{

        Connection con = ConectaMySQL.obterConexao ();
        PreparedStatement statement = con.prepareStatement ("SELECT tpa.descricao_artigo, tsp.descricao_situacao_processo FROM processo_judicial AS pj INNER JOIN tp_situacao_processo as tsp on tsp.cd_situacao_processo = pj.cd_situacao_processo  INNER JOIN tp_artigo as tpa ON tpa.cd_artigo = pj.cd_artigo INNER JOIN suspeito_processo AS sproc ON sproc.num_processo = pj.num_processo INNER JOIN suspeito AS s ON s.cd_suspeito = sproc.cd_suspeito WHERE s.nome_suspeito = '"+nome_suspeito+"' AND s.cpf_suspeito = '"+cpf_suspeito+"' AND s.rg_suspeito = '"+rg_suspeito+"'");

        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery ();

        while (result.next()){
            ProcessoJudicial obj = new ProcessoJudicial();
            obj.setDescricao_artigo(result.getString("descricao_artigo"));
            obj.setDescricao_situacao_processo(result.getString("descricao_situacao_processo"));                
            results.add(obj);
        }
        result.close();
        statement.close();
        return results;
    }
    catch ( Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace ();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Deu certo consegui testá-lo no SOAPUI, só falta funcionar na minha aplicação e gerar a tabela no Android. O body do envelope de resposta ficou assim.

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapenv:Body>
  <ns:consultarResponse xmlns:ns="http://wsprototipo.br.com" xmlns:ax21="http://wsprototipo.br.com/xsd">
     <ns:return xsi:type="ax21:ProcessoJudicial" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <ax21:descricao_artigo>Lesão Corporal</ax21:descricao_artigo>
        <ax21:descricao_situacao_processo>Transito</ax21:descricao_situacao_processo>
        <ax21:num_processo xsi:nil="true"/>
     </ns:return>
  </ns:consultarResponse>
```

Comment: Luiz, só uma dica, não faça concatenação de strings para sql, senão seu código fica desprotegido contra ataques de sql injection

Comment: Como eu faria sem concatenar?

Comment: muito grande para um comentário. A forma é (se realmente é c#) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters(v=vs.110).aspx e o q você quer evitar pode ser visto [neste link](http://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inje%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_SQL)

Comment: É java, mas é a mesma coisa! (Y)Obrigado.